# Count the number of characters and words in Array

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, arrays

How to count number of characters & words in array in C#?

For e.g.:

```
char[] arr= "My name is ABC XYZ".Tochararray();
```

should return 5 as number of words and 18 (space is counted as character) as number of characters.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a string, not an array of ints.

Comment: that correct!. Question updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly assign a string to an array of integers/chars in c#

```
string s = "My name is ABC XYZ";

int l = s.Length // 18 chars;
int w = s.Split(' ').Count(); // 5 words
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one using LINQ for the trivial (space-based) word count:

```
string s = "My name is ABC XYZ";
int l = s.Length;                   // 18
int w = s.Count(x => x == ' ') + 1; // 5
```

This will usually perform better than a `Split()` call, because it handles the string as an enumerable stream of characters and just counts as it goes rather than creating an array of strings to store the words in.